# Blocking "pokes" of our system

Tags: apache-2.2, security, brute-force-attacks, intrusion-prevention

We get **tons** of these in our apache error log every day.

```
[Wed Oct 17 03:27:37 2018] [error] [client 103.41.124.159] File does not exist: /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
[Wed Oct 17 03:27:37 2018] [error] [client 103.41.124.159] File does not exist: /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin
[Wed Oct 17 03:27:37 2018] [error] [client 103.41.124.159] File does not exist: /var/www/html/pmd
[Wed Oct 17 03:27:37 2018] [error] [client 103.41.124.159] File does not exist: /var/www/html/pma
[Wed Oct 17 03:27:37 2018] [error] [client 103.41.124.159] File does not exist: /var/www/html/PMA
[Wed Oct 17 03:27:38 2018] [error] [client 103.41.124.159] File does not exist: /var/www/html/PMA2
[Wed Oct 17 03:27:38 2018] [error] [client 103.41.124.159] File does not exist: /var/www/html/pmamy
[Wed Oct 17 03:27:38 2018] [error] [client 103.41.124.159] File does not exist: /var/www/html/pmamy2
[Wed Oct 17 03:27:38 2018] [error] [client 103.41.124.159] File does not exist: /var/www/html/mysql
[Wed Oct 17 03:27:38 2018] [error] [client 103.41.124.159] File does not exist: /var/www/html/admin
```

Is there a way to:

1. Block these from getting logged?
2. Block the IP addresses that do this? Build a list of them to block?

This particular IP had 54 different "pokes". They come from different IP addresses so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Have a look at fail2ban?

Comment: no, what is it?

Comment: fail2ban has filters for these built in. Just enable them and it'll start blocking them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Block these from getting logged?

This does not seem a good idea : getting rid of logs will never improve security :)

2. Block the IP addresses that do this? Build a list of them to block?

That's exactly the job fail2ban was designed for. By default, it blocks this IP temporarly.

Maybe the solution you are looking for is fail2ban.

> Fail2ban scans log files (e.g. /var/log/apache/error_log) and bans IPs that show the malicious signs -- too many password failures, seeking for exploits, etc. Generally Fail2Ban is then used to update firewall rules to reject the IP addresses for a specified amount of time, although any arbitrary other action (e.g. sending an email) could also be configured.

Source : https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page